# Will developers listen to hostile podcast? (aka wrong URL of podcast iframe breaking it)

Tags: bug, blog, podcast, embedding

In the [Will developers return to hostile offices?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/12/01/will-developers-return-to-hostile-offices/) blog post, there is iframe pointing to the podcast episode.

However, it's broken:

[image: broken podcast iframe]

For reference, this is how it should look like: (taken from [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/12/08/one-weird-trick-for-teaching-users-your-software/))

[image: valid podcast iframe]

The cause for the bug is wrong URL used in the `<iframe>`. In the broken post it's using the [direct URL of the episode](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/will-developers-return-to-hostile-offices) while it should use [special embed URL](https://player.simplecast.com/2df79274-24d9-4cbe-b0d0-ce2e82afb7e7), which can be found by clicking the "embed" button in the episode:

[image: embded button in the podcast episode]

Can this please be fixed?

Also, as a bonus, would be great to have link to the [podcast transcript](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/will-developers-return-to-hostile-offices/transcript).